# Is it possible to upload android apk file in test flight site..

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, android-activity, testflight

How to upload file .apk file in test flight site, Is it possible now. I tried for uploading file but it shows
Support for Android beta testing on TestFlight has been discontinued as of March 21, 2014.
We are refocusing TestFlight on iOS and we will continue to support app development on iOS.

Comment: Ya that's true.It's no more available for Android....

Comment: Apple bought the company behind TestFlight and have removed any Android support. It is going to be completely integrated in Xcode en iTunes Connect with the iOS 8 release.

Comment: Thank u guys if u know anything please tell me...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TestFlight was the option but not anymore for new Apps, only old register app can be uploaded, for beta testing another good platform is [Hockey](http://hockeyapp.net) but it's paid.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Google Play Store Developer Account you can use their beta testing feature to give people access to Android apps for beta testing. See : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en